# WooCommerce comments_template Filter Not Firing

Tags: filters, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a template file that is being called via wp_ajax that returns data from a specific WooCommerce product.

In the "tabs" section of the template file every tab is working fine:

- Description - Good
- Additional Information - Good
- Custom Tab - Good

The only tab not rendering tab panel content is the reviews tab.

Interestingly the Tab Link (`li`) shows up with the correct tab count. However, when you click the link and the review panel is no longer display:none and set as active - no content is shown. (This has been verified in dev tools).

The code that is calling all of the individual tabs is:

```
<?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ) ?>
```

Where `$tab` is an array with:

- title
- priority
- callback

The reviews tab calls the WooCommerce specified `comments_template` callback.

This is *supposed* to trigger the hook in `class WC_Template_Loader`:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', array( __CLASS__, 'comments_template_loader' ) );
```

In testing I've var_dumped the `WC_Template_Loader` init function, and the init function, where the add_filters are located, is running.

However, when I var_dump a test string in the `comments_template_loader()` function, nothing is returned.

As an aside - all other WooCommerce generated content is rendered correctly (`global $woocommerce, $post, $product` are declared).

Why is this filter not running when seemingly all other default Wordpress tab filters are?

Comment: This is a woocommerce template file located within your theme?  Possible the native tools are grabbing the wrong file?  (hint) I'm hoping you aren't changing a single byte of code anywhere within the Plugin Woocommerce directory.  (hint: I've been burnt before working on the wrong custom template.. now I always include `<!-- custom_filename.php -->` at the top of all customization's, then religiously ensure filenames are accurate.)

Comment: @zipzit The changes in the WC code are strictly to see what is running. The problem seems to be that the file is never being grabbed. I.e. the `comments_template_loader()` never runs to process the file so the add_filter never is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for anyone looking to include the WooCommerce review tab not on an actual single-product page here's the secret sauce:

In your template file, you need:

```
global $withcomments;
$withcomments = true;
```

Then add a filter for the comments template:

```
//add filter to use our custom review template
add_filter('comments_template','{{YOUR_HELPER_FUNCTION}}');

/**
* Hook function for using custom quickview review template
* @return [string] [file path to the template]
*/
function YOUR_HELPER_FUNCTION(){
    $template = LCS_DIR . "../templates/tmpl-single-product-reviews.php";
    if ( file_exists( $template ) )
        return( $template );
}
```

`$template` is the full file path to the template file you want to use.

BadaBing and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could change the callback of the reviews tab to your own function which calls a custom template.

**functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'fpusa_custom_review_tab', 98 );
function fpusa_custom_review_tab( $tabs ) {
    // change the callback for the reviews tab
    $tabs['reviews']['callback'] = 'fpusa_get_comments_template';
    return $tabs;
}

function fpusa_get_comments_template(){
    // looks for a file in /yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/customer_reviews.php
    wc_get_template('single-product/customer_reviews.php');
}
```